# Проблема в коде игры камень ножницы бумага

Tags: python, if, python-3.8

Не работает игра камень/ножницы/бумага. Я написал самым простым алгоритмом, с `if`

```
import random

input('Viberete"noznici,kolodec or bymaga": ')
random_number = random.randint(1, 3)


if input == "noznici" and random_number == 1:
    print("Nichya, ya toze vibral noznici")
elif input == "noznici" and random_number == 2:
    print("Ti proigral, ya vibral kolodec")
elif input == "noznici" and random_number == 3:
    print("Ti vigral, ya vibral bymagy")

if input == "kolodec" and random_number == 1:
    print("Ti vigral, ya vibral noznici")
elif input == "kolodec" and random_number == 2:
    print("Nichya, ya toze vibral kolodec")
elif input == "kolodec" and random_number == 3:
    print("Ti proigral, ya vibral bymagy")

if input == "bymaga" and random_number == 1:
    print("Ti proigral, ya vibral noznici")
elif input == "bymaga" and random_number == 2:
    print("Ti vigral, ya vibral kolodec")
elif input == "bymaga" or random_number == 3:
    print("Nichya, ya toze vibral bymagy")
```

Comment: а почему транслитом? и какая проблема?

Comment: Вы неправильно используете `input()`

Comment: Spasibo za otvet, ispolzyu translit potomychto na danniy moment klaviatyra s angliyskoi raskladkoi.

Answer (score 1):

`input` - функция. когда вы сравниваете функцию со строкой, поянтно, что у вас ничего не получится.
Эта функция возвращает ответ пользователя. Вы же его никуда не сохраняете, а надо сохранить в переменную, это я и сделал в строке `answer = input("")`
Удачи в изучении `python`!

```
import random

answer = input('Viberete"noznici,kolodec or bymaga": ')
random_number = random.randint(1, 3)

if answer == "noznici" and random_number == 1:
    print("Nichya, ya toze vibral noznici")
elif answer == "noznici" and random_number == 2:
    print("Ti proigral, ya vibral kolodec")
elif answer == "noznici" and random_number == 3:
    print("Ti vigral, ya vibral bymagy")

if answer == "kolodec" and random_number == 1:
    print("Ti vigral, ya vibral noznici")
elif answer == "kolodec" and random_number == 2:
    print("Nichya, ya toze vibral kolodec")
elif answer == "kolodec" and random_number == 3:
    print("Ti proigral, ya vibral bymagy")

if answer == "bymaga" and random_number == 1:
    print("Ti proigral, ya vibral noznici")
elif answer == "bymaga" and random_number == 2:
    print("Ti vigral, ya vibral kolodec")
elif answer == "bymaga" or random_number == 3:
    print("Nichya, ya toze vibral bymagy")
```

Comment: но этот код все равно кривой, можно сделать лучше

Comment: Можно, конечно, но ответ предназначен для начинающего. Здесь не стоит использовать более сложные конструкции.

Comment: Spasibo za otvet! Ochen pomog

Comment: @Ostap Всегда пожалуйста!:) примите ответ как правильный?

Answer (score 1):

Нужно поменять код таким образом.

```
import random

choose = input('Viberete noznici,kolodec or bymaga": ')
random_number = random.randint(1, 3)

if choose == "noznici" and random_number == 1:
    print("Nichya, ya toze vibral noznici")
elif choose == "noznici" and random_number == 2:
    print("Ti proigral, ya vibral kolodec")
elif choose == "noznici" and random_number == 3:
    print("Ti vigral, ya vibral bymagy")

if choose == "kolodec" and random_number == 1:
    print("Ti vigral, ya vibral noznici")
elif choose == "kolodec" and random_number == 2:
    print("Nichya, ya toze vibral kolodec")
elif choose == "kolodec" and random_number == 3:
    print("Ti proigral, ya vibral bymagy")

if choose == "bymaga" and random_number == 1:
    print("Ti proigral, ya vibral noznici")
elif choose == "bymaga" and random_number == 2:
    print("Ti vigral, ya vibral kolodec")
elif choose == "bymaga" or random_number == 3:
    print("Nichya, ya toze vibral bymagy")
```

Я заношу результат функции input() в переменную choose. А потом проверяю в if равняется ли choose bymaga/kolodec/noznici.